# How to format serilog property names?

Tags: c#, asp.net, serilog

I'm using `Serilog` and `Serilog.Formatting.Compact` to write logs into a file. How can I dynamically format property names?

I want each property name to include its type.

For example: bool_property_name, string_property_name, date_property_name....

```cs
logger.Information("this is a message with {property_name}", "value");
```

or

```cs
logger
    .ForContext("property_name", "value")
    .Information("this is a message");
```

should be in the log:

```
{ ...., string_property_name: "value" }
```

Comment: there's no such mechanism out of the box (go read the source). Question though: why?!

Comment: Problems with elasticsearch mappings. For when I have several properties with the same name

Comment: Ah, I guess it's worth looking in the repo's issues to see if it's come up - perhaps worth asking in https://gitter.im/serilog for what others have done

Comment: Why don't you add that yourself in the logger.Information row?
I.e. just write: logger.Information("this is a message with {string_property_name}", "value");
Maybe you have this log-row at a very generic place but otherwise you will always know what property you have when entering the log row manually.

Comment: I could also rename the property but im afraid it might happen again to another developer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is the solution i found.

Some important points about this solution to notice:

- It doesn't format the message template.
- It formats every property - including properties added by third party enrichers for example.
- Its still not in production. I will update if any bugs are found.

```cs
public class LogEventPropertiesNameFormatter
{
    public void Format(LogEvent logEvent)
    {
        var keys = new List<string>(logEvent.Properties.Keys);

        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(Visit(key, logEvent.Properties[key]));
            logEvent.RemovePropertyIfPresent(key);
        }
    }

    private LogEventProperty Visit(string name, LogEventPropertyValue value)
    {
        switch (value)
        {
        case null:
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
        case ScalarValue scalar:
            return VisitScalar(name, scalar);
        case SequenceValue sequence:
            return VisitSequence(name, sequence);
        case StructureValue scalar:
            return VisitStructure(name, scalar);
        case DictionaryValue dictionary:
            return VisitDictionary(name, dictionary);
        default:
            return new LogEventProperty(name, value);
    }

    private LogEventProperty VisitDictionary(string name, DictionaryValue dictionary)
    {
        var formattedElements = new Dictionary<ScalarValue, LogEventPropertyValue>(dictionary.Elements.Count);

        foreach (var element in dictionary.Elements)
        {
            var property = Visit(element.Key.Value.ToString(), element.Value);
            formattedElements.Add(new ScalarValue(property.Name), property.Value);
        }

        return LogEventProperty($"dict_{name}", new DictionaryValue(formattedElements));
    }

    private LogEventProperty VisitStructure(string name, StructureValue structure)
    {
        var properties = structure.Properties.Select(p => Visit(p.Name, p.Value));
        return new LogEventProperty($"struct_{name}", new StructureValue(properties));
    }

    private LogEventProperty VisitSequence(string name, SequenceValue sequence)
    {
        var elements = sequence.Elements.Select(e => Visit(null, e).Value);
        return new LogEventProperty($"seq_{name}", new SequenceValue(elements));
    }

    private LogEventProperty VisitScalar(string name, ScalarValue scalar)
    {
        return new LogEventProperty($"{GetScalarValueType(scalar)}_{name}", scalar);
    }

    private string GetScalarValueType(ScalarValue value)
    {
        switch (value.Value)
        {
            case null:
                return "null";
            case string _:
            case TimeSpan _:
                return "s";
            case int _:
            case uint _:
            case long _:
            case ulong _:
            case decimal _:
            case byte _:
            case sbyte _:
            case short _:
            case ushort _:
            case double _:
            case float _:
                return "n";
            case bool _:
                return "b";
            case DateTime _:
            case DateTimeOffset _:
                return "d";
            default:
                return "o";
        }
    }
}

public class CompactJsonFormatterTypeOverride : ITextFormatter
{
    private readonly ITextFormatter _textFormatter;
    private readonly LogEventPropertiesNameFormatter _logEventPropertiesNameFormatter;

    public CompactJsonFormatterTypeOverride()
    {
        _textFormatter = new CompactJsonFormatter();
        _logEventPropertiesNameFormatter = new LogEventPropertiesNameFormatter();
    }

    public void Format(LogEvent logEvent, TextWriter output)
    {
        _logEventPropertiesNameFormatter.Format(logEvent);
        _textFormatter.Format(logEvent, output);
    }
}
```

Then in the logger configuration:

```cs
new LoggerConfiguration().
    WriteTo.File(new CompactJsonFormatterTypeOverride(), "log.log")
    .CreateLogger();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
logger.Information($"this is a message with {property_name}");
```

You can log your request within message just putting the $ in start { } braces for property.

Comment: But then I won't have the property at all

Comment: Ok, are you using any there properites ?

Comment: Yes. I'm querying them in elasticsearch

Comment: which are them ?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand what you're asking and for what purpose. I have properties such as requests, id's, etc...

Comment: No problem because sometimes we have understanding problem that why problem takes time, Can you please tell me your dynamic property names? that would be great.

Comment: Take request for example. Each request is has different I want to log, in one request the parameter is a string and in another its a number

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195136/discussion-between-shahzad-khan-and-mei).